# Keysight's Advanced Design System users, what's wrong with this common drain circuit simulation?

Tags: mosfet, simulation, fet, ads, common-drain

For those of you that use Advanced Design System (ADS), from this circuit:

[image]

Fundamental Frequency for transient simulation tool is set to 1 GHz.

Yet, I'm getting this output:

[image]

Main question:

Since this is common drain, VOUT should at most have the same amplitude as VIN. Probably even negative shift, since I didn't change the voltage threshold (I haven't got to tweaking parameters yet). So what's up with the positive DC bias? Why is the amplification significantly less than unity?

Other questions:

1. Also, what's that Transient Response at the very first cycle of VOUT? Why would a semiconductor have a Transient Response? Is it because of the "inductance" on the drain and source of a MOSFET?
2. Lastly, why is it that this simulation does not work on very low frequencies? I first started with 1 Hz scale for everything (just change all units from 1 GHz below to 1 Hz). The M1 just acted like a 1kOhm constant resistor.

I also simulated this in the 1 kHz scale (replaced all units from GHz in the pics to kHz, did the same with Fundamental Frequency). This is the output:

[image]

Even here, the DC bias is nearly the same and the amplification is much, much less. It also lags by 90°. Why?

I'm starting to think it's either just using the wrong component or there was a set of parameters to fill-in for this component to get this to work.

The continuation of this discussion: [Keysight's Advanced Design System users, what's wrong with this simulation - II](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217538/keysights-advanced-design-system-users-whats-wrong-with-this-simulation-ii)

Comment: You are simulating at 1GHz!!! The MOSFET is doing nothing at that frequency, its just conducting a bit, The output is due to capacitive coupling gate to source. 1GHz!

Comment: Did you have a look at that mosfets datasheet? Things like turn on relay time and so on? And I am pretty sure it works fine at 1kHz, your expectation is just wrong

Comment: @user1582568: I see. So that's why there's a Transient Response. I thought this (GHz) was the fundamental frequency to make the simulation run, seeing that this package is for HF and that I was getting a flat line on VOUT at the Hz range (as stated in 2)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I think you should see my second point above.

Comment: @kozner: Your expectation is just wrong there, your "gain" will probably like 0.3 or something there

Comment: @kozner, now we have the real problem. Have you tried a DC op point simulation? What results do you get?

Comment: Don't add new questions after your old one, this is not now SE works.

Comment: continuation of the discussion: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217538/keysights-advanced-design-system-users-whats-wrong-with-this-simulation-ii

Comment: Keysight's in the EDA tool business? Wonder how many limbs and first born children they want for that...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [your MOSFET's datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfz44n.pdf) page 2 (like @PlasmaHH proposed above).

You'll see that it is not able to work properly at 1 GHz since it's turn-on and turn-off delay times are about tens of ns which obviously waaaay too slow to operate at this frequency. You should try with a component better suited for RF applications (or just decrease your operating frequency).

Answer (score 0):

\$v_{gs} << 2 (V_{GSQ} - V_{TN})\$

Here your \$v_{gs}\$ is \$3\sin(\theta)\$.

So condition is not holding.....

See [Microelectronics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073380644) by Donald A. Neamen, 4th Edition, chapter 4.1.1 on page 208.